# What does the width and height parameter represent @ react-pdf-highlighter

Tags: reactjs, pdf, pdf.js

I was implementing 
https://github.com/agentcooper/react-pdf-highlighter

What does the width and height parameter represent? (file link: https://github.com/agentcooper/react-pdf-highlighter/blob/master/demo/src/test-highlights.js)

[image]

Comment: width and height in pixels?

Comment: seems likely related to a color gradient scheme: https://www.w3schools.com/graphics/svg_grad_linear.asp

Comment: no those don't behave like pixels @Ahmad